# Help with downloading the network

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, datadir

I'm trying to download the network in a different drive of my computer, not my C drive, because I don't have much space left on that one. I change the directory, H drive, while in the command prompt  and write geth --rpc and it would start to download . But towards my C drive not the H drive where I want it to.  Also I can't find the file where it downloaded and I only have 5 Gb left. Any help?